# Kusto Sort by aggregate like Count

Tags: sorting, aggregate, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm new to Kusto/KQL but experienced in T-SQL. I am trying to get a list of exceptions, group them by type, add a count, and order by that count descending.
In SQL it would be:

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(Type)
FROM exceptions
GROUP BY Type
ORDER BY COUNT(Type) Desc
```

I've managed everything but the sort.

```
exceptions
| summarize count() by type
```

I cannot work out how to sort by an aggregate. I've tried `| sort by count() desc`, `| sort by count() by type desc`, `| as c | sort by c desc`, `| extend c = summarize count() by type | sort by c desc`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default column name for `count()` aggregation is `count_`, so:

```
exceptions
| summarize count() by type
| sort by count_ desc
```

Or, with explicitly naming the column:

```
exceptions
| summarize CountExceptions = count() by type
| sort by CountExceptions desc
```